# Download package via apt for another architecture

Tags: apt

I am currently in a architecture amd64, so when I try `apt-get download vlc`, it downloaded the appropriate architecture for my system, but how can I download the i386 version via apt?

It's for export to another system that doesn't have internet connection, also is there is any way to download any dependencies that follow?

Comment: Do you want to install it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can, just append `:i386` to the download command, like this:

```
sudo apt-get download <package>:i386
```

So for you:

```
sudo apt-get download vlc:i386
```

<s>I am unaware of any way of automatically downloading a packages dependencies, besides `build-dep` but that won't work in your case.</s>

After poking in the manpage a bit more, I have found that you can, in fact, use `build-dep` to an extent like this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep --download-only vlc:i386
```

Which will then download the required packages into the current directory. Note however, that `build-dep` is looking at compiling the package from source, not installing it from a `.deb` so it will suggest things like `build-essential` and `gcc` which may be needed to compile vlc, but not necessarily install from a `.deb`.

It may be easier to list vlc's main dependencies with `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache depends vlc:i386
```

If you want to filter by just depends use:

```
apt-cache depends vlc:i386 | grep 'Depends'
```

Note that some packages, like `libc6` come by default in Ubuntu, so you won't need to download those. If you just want to download all the dependencies and deal with whether you need them or not later you can use this script:

```
for i in $(apt-cache depends vlc:i386 | grep -E 'Depends|Recommends|Suggests' | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | sed -e s/'<'/''/ -e s/'>'/''/); do sudo apt-get download $i 2>>no32.txt; done
```

This will download all the dependent, recommended, and suggested packages and reroute any errors to `no32.txt`. You should take a look in there when you're done, because some needed packages that don't have i386 versions (i.e. they aren't binaries) will be in there.

Just `apt-get download` those.

Note that this script isn't very smart, it doesn't take a lot of things into account, so you may get some silly errors, it should work in general however.

Comment: And what about build-dep package:i386?

Comment: @enedil build-dep downloads *and* installs, so this would install a bunch of i386 packages on his machine, which is not what he wants. See man apt-get for details.

Comment: There is also an `aptitude download` command. Not sure if it is multiarch enabled though.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, aptitude can do just about everything `apt-get` can.

Comment: What repository enables multiarch searches? as far as I can tell only certain distributions of ubuntu has the repositories that would yield any results.

Comment: @saterHater I believe Ubuntu stopped building i386 packages with 19.10 or 20.04 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/intel-32bit-packages-on-ubuntu-from-19-10-onwards/11263). If that's not what you meant then please further elaborate.

Comment: yeah. I was curious about how my distribution wasn't finding some of the other architectures listed on the canonical repo front-end (armhf, arm64, etc). a `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and a read into the `sources.list` can tell me what architectures I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out if you just want to download a package and all the dependencies as a specific architecture, there is a sneaky way to do it that shouldn't permanently impact your system. For bonus points/isolation you can do this in a Docker container to really avoid messing with your host system at all other than a folder shared in to save the deb packages in.

```
# You can supply a space separated list or just one package
DESIRED_PACKAGES="dnsmasq-base"

# You need to tell dpkg about a new "foreign" architecture
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64

# Now we update the package lists and tell it to ONLY get the architecture we want
sudo apt update -o APT::Architecture="arm64" -o APT::Architectures="arm64"

# Now call install, but with download-only, because it will fetch the dependencies where apt-get download only grabs a single package
sudo apt-get install --download-only -o Dir::Cache="./" -o Dir::Cache::archives="./" dnsmasq-base -y
```

If you aren't just doing `i386` on an `amd64` system (semi-compatible), then on the system where you actually want to install these packages, you will probably need to `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` in the folder you save them, because the newer `sudo apt install ./some-package.deb` gets confused by the dependency resolution and won't behave nicely.

Docker version

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/work -w /work debian:buster
```

Then run the same script from above, but you won't need `sudo` because the container runs as root by default. Once you have run the commands and downloaded the files, you can type `exit` to get out of the container, and then you will need to `sudo chown $USER: *.deb` to allow your host user to access the deb files to move/copy/delete.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the answers posted by others here (and there) I came up with the following script that might save someone's time:

```
docker run --name arm64-packages --rm -dit ubuntu:20.04 bash
docker exec arm64-packages dpkg --add-architecture arm64
docker exec -i arm64-packages bash <<EOF
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arm64.list <<LIST
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal main restricted
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-updates main restricted
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal universe
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-updates universe
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal multiverse
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-updates multiverse
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
LIST
EOF
docker exec arm64-packages apt-get update || : # Is expected to return error.
docker exec arm64-packages apt-get download libc6:arm64
package_path=$(docker exec arm64-packages ls / | grep libc6)
docker cp arm64-packages:$package_path ./libc6_arm64.deb
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I use it for cross-builds to armhf and arm64 from amd64: https://github.com/devcoin/core/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using chroot or proot on the host system to create an isolated filesystem of the appropriate architecture. You can then run apt in that emulated environment to install the architecture specific packages just as if you were on a machine of that architecture. It does run a bit slower since it is emulating the architecture, but you then have a rootfs that you can deploy to your other device of a different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing the output of `apt install --simulate` and then run `apt download` for each package.